# Getting the Date('YYYY-MM-DD') from a text representation of a timestamp in milliseconds in Oracle

Tags: oracle, date, datetime, timestamp, sql-timestamp

We have a DB that is storing the timestamp (in milliseconds since Unix Epoch, Jan 1st 1970) in a **text** column in a Oracle DB. We would like to get a Date('YYYY-MM-DD') from that

I tried the following but it doesn't seem to work:

```
 TO_CHAR(cast(trunc(TO_NUMBER(created_on)/1000),'YYYY-MM-DD') as timestamp)
```

Comment: Can you provide more details about this field?  Is it the number of milliseconds since a specific point in time?  Otherwise, I don't see how it can be translated to a specific date.

Comment: Milleseconds from beginning of time?

Comment: It is the unix/epoch timestamp just in milliseconds.